# What is the best data type to accurately store dates and times for a schedule in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am creating an application that allows for people to schedule an appointment for a doctor using spring boot. Part of the application contains a table to store the available times and dates for a particular doctor.

The attributes for the table are:

- Id
- Doctor Id
- Time
- Date
- Type
- Comment

My question is what data types would be best to use for the "time" and "date" attribute in Spring Boot that would best allow me to accurately represent and store this data?

I was think a form of list, but I don't know how if it would be the best option.

Comment: For me you are missing something in the table attributes as the representation of an available time needs to start and end. So I would add an endTime or a duration. It might be that you assume that all doctors use the same duration for an appointment and, in that case, I would use a string/varchar for the time in 24h format (i.e. "09:00" or "15:45"). It's easy enough to work with.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to store Date and time in separate fields than use [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) and [LocalTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) classes. If you want to keep them in one field you can use [LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) or if you want to have a reference to exact moment you will have to have offset reference, and than you will need to use [OffsetDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) or [ZonedDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html). In general, read up on package java.time.

Comment: My question is, if I want to store the various times a doctor is available on a particular date, what data type would be best used? Would it best something like a list?

Comment: Use map with LocalDate as a key and List<LocalTime> as a value

Answer (score 0):

The answer that Michael gave tells you what data type should you use in your Spring app and you can either create a list of LocalDateTime values to store all the available times or you can implement that rather in your front-end because it would be a lot easier to have an array of hours from your open time until your closing time and retrieving the existing appointments only showing the hours that the doctor is available. After all the implementation would be a lot easier in the front-end assuming you implement one.

Comment: So it would be best to implement the available times and dates in the frontend? Should I just store available times and dates in individual arrays for now?

Comment: you should store the dates that are occupied in the backend and retrieve them in the front end and implement the comparison on the program and see which hours are occupied and which are not. again this is how i would personally do it and how i see fit but there may be other solutions there

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).